# Variable referencing and how pointers interact with memory

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

When a variable is created such as:

```
int x = 5;
```

it will be stored somewhere in memory, cool.

However when I change the value of the variable by doing the following:

```
x = 10;
```

What happens in memory?

Does the new value of `x`  overwrite the old value using the same memory address?

or is it that the new value is stored in a new memory address and then the old address is deleted?

This question arose when I came across pointers. It seems that using pointers to change the value of a variable is the same as defining the variable with another value.

this is my code (most of it are comments (lol)):

```
#include "iostream"

int main()
{
    int x = 5; // declaring and defining x to be 5
    int *xPointer = &x; // declare and define xPointer as a pointer to store the reference of x

    printf("%d\n",x); // print the value of x
    printf("%p\n",xPointer); // print the reference of x

    x = 10; //changing value of x

    printf("%d\n",x); //print new value of x
    printf("%p\n",xPointer); //print the reference of x to see if it changed when the value of x changed

    *xPointer = 15; //changing the value of x using a pointer

    printf("%d\n",x); //print new value of x
    printf("%p\n",xPointer); //print reference of x to see if it changed

    return 0;
}
```

this is the output:

```
5
00AFF9C0
10
00AFF9C0
15
00AFF9C0
```

As you can see the memory addresses are the same, hence what is the point of pointers (pun intended).

Comment: If it helps, the address of an object can never change throughout it's lifetime under any circumstances.

Comment: So the address of x will never change?

Comment: @RafaelFranco: `&x` will never change; that's correct.

Comment: "what is the point of pointers" - there are many. Some are: suppose you have a huge object (say 10MB) that you want to pass to a function; doing that by value means an expensive copy. Passing a pointer (or reference (which is basically a pointer under the hood)) instead is cheap. Also, sometimes you have objects that cannot be copied or moved in memory, but you can still pass pointers to them around. Sometimes you need to access something at an offset into an object and forming a pointer to the object + the offset is the most convenient. And more.

Comment: Go on and read more about C/C++. You are in a very infant stage and that's why you're asking such a question. Once you get to know a little more about the language, you'll get your answer yourself.

Comment: Pointers are useful for speaking about where something is. Real-world examples: houses usually don’t move around, but street addresses are pretty handy despite that; airplane seats are fixed, but “the person in seat 12C” is not a pointless phrase; (and so on...)

Answer (score 2):

When you declare `int x = 5;` you are saying that `x` has automatic storage duration and is initialised with the value `5`.

For the lifetime of `x`, a pointer to `x` (i.e. `&x`) will have the same value.

You can change the value of `x` with the assignment `x = 10` or via a pointer dereference `*xPointer = 15` having set `int* xPointer = &x;`.

The language standard mentions nothing about the pointer value being a memory address, although it might be. That's a common misconception as to how the language works.

(Indeed a new value of `x` *might* cause the location in memory to change. That's permitted by the language so long as the pointer value doesn't change. An operating system may well do something similar to this, in the interests of obviating memory defragmentation.)

Comment: I feel the last point may distract from the core of the answer, that pointers to `x` remain valid.